# how to set xpath using div role and aria-label in kotlin

Tags: selenium, kotlin, xpath, appium, xpath-1.0

Here sharing the HTML and xpath code what I wrote. But the click event is not working.

```
<div role="button" class="U2GHA6fgb BHYSYYBxpf" aria-label="Add food" aria-disabled="false" data-tooltip="Add food">
    <span class="DPvwYc" aria-hidden="true">icon</span>
```

I am setting xpath as like below. But the click event not working

```
var xpath1 = "//div[contains(@role,\"button\") and contains(@aria-label,\"Add food\")]"
webDriver.findElement<WebElement>(By.xpath(xpath1)).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
var xpath1 = "//div[@aria-label='Add food' and data-tooltip='Add food']/span"
webDriver.findElement<WebElement>(By.xpath(xpath1)).click()
```

Comment: Thank you! the click event worked without appending span in xpath and maximized the browser.